# How do I declare individual array values in Python?

Tags: python, xmpp

I am currently playing around with the [python-jabberbot](http://thp.io/2007/python-jabberbot/) and am having trouble creating a simple method which sends a random sentence. I am not proficient in python so I am wondering where I am going wrong. I have a feeling the way I am declaring the array is my downfall:

```
def whatdoyouknow(self, mess, args):
        """random response"""   
        string[0] = 'this is a longish sentence about things'
        string[1] = 'this is a longish sentence about things number 2'
        string[2] = 'this is a longish sentence about things number 3'

        i = random.randint(0, 2)
        return string[i]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You define a list literal by putting the elements in square brackets:

```
string = ['this is a longish sentence about things',
          'this is a longish sentence about things number 2',
          'this is a longish sentence about things number 3']
```

Alternatively, you build the list by defining an empty list, then appending the elements:

```
string = []
string.append('this is a longish sentence about things')
string.append('this is a longish sentence about things number 2')
string.append('this is a longish sentence about things number 3')
```

I strongly recommend you read the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) before continuing, it explains building python types and how to manipulate them for you.

Comment: @Switchkick -- As a side note, in your example, you could use a `tuple` as well.  In that case, replace the square brackets with parenthesis.  But, definitely read the tutorial ... That will make is more clear the difference between `list` and `tuple` types (One difference being that you can't `.append` to a tuple).